# First order sentence only satisfiable in finite models if domain has an even number of elements

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

As the title says, I'm trying to find a first order sentence for which all finite models which satisfy it have a domain with an even number of elements and for which *every* finite set
with an even number of elements is the domain of some model of the sentence.

The problem I'm attempting requires that I do this in the language $L=\{ f\}$ where $f$ is a unary function and is the only non-logical symbol (so I can't use any relations).

One option I think *might* only be satisfiable by even sets is the sentence $\forall x ((f(f(x))=x) \land\neg(f(x)=x))$, but I'm not sure how I'd go about explaining no model with an odd finite domain could satisfy it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your candidate sentence works perfectly. Re: verification, I think with problems like this it's easy to start second-guessing oneself. Let me propose the following hints *(the motto being "don't try too hard")*:

- Show that a (finite) set is even iff it can be written as a disjoint union of two-element sets *(more simply: iff it can be partitioned into pairs)*.
- Now suppose $M$ satisfies your sentence. Can you think of a way to use $f$ to break $M$ into a bunch of pairs?

  - *(HINT: can you show that $M$ satisfies $\forall x,y[f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y]$? This is really the key part of the verification.)*
- Finally, you need to show that your sentence has a model of size $2k$ for every positive integer $k$. Consider (for example) the set $\{0,1\}\times \{1,2,...,k\}$ - do you see a way to turn this into a model of your sentence?